# showing sliding web pages like facebook/ iphone springboard

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am looking to implement something similar to the dashboard of facebook app where you can slide between pages. The page I am talking about has bullets type thing at the bottom to indicate on which page are you. This is same as the one we see in Edit mode on iphone's springboard (main screen).

Is there a control/library for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes , its possible ,

Try Three20 Library - TTLauncherView Facebook Uses this Library

http://iosguy.com/2010/10/19/tthree20-a-brief-ttlauncherview-tutorial/

or this one https://github.com/rigoneri/myLauncher

Hope this Helps

Comment: Thanks that does solve the problem, although I managed to work out with UIScrollView and UIPageControl itself since my use case was a little smaller than what I initially asked. But your answer needs to be accepted!

Comment: @Ankit : k hen try this , http://www.xprogress.com/post-53-how-to-build-uiscrollview-with-page-control/